# DialogFragment fullscreen shows padding on sides

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I am creating a custom DialogFragment that is displayed underneath the actionbar. So far everything works great. The layout parameters for dialog fragment are `match_parent` for width and `wrap_content` for height.

I have tried every solution including setting the layout parameters .width and by getting Display size and removing the themes. However no matter what there is a small amount of space on left, right and top side of the dialog that is invisible. I need to know how to remove this space so it actually matches the width of the screen and hopefully gets rid of the top padding as well.

Comment: Try to change the style/theme of the dialog

Comment: try the below and let me know if it works. the dialog takes the full space available.

Comment: Yes I have, there are a few themes that get rid of the padding but also removes all other parameter set to the fragment.. The dialogFragment simply displays as fullscreen (match_parent on width and height and removes any x offset to account for the actionabr). Which is not something I am looking for.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I figured it out using custom dialog theme. windowIsFloating true will get rid of the background but will add some extra space underneath the background as a background. In which case you can use windowBackground @null to erase it.

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Usage:

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Thank you to Raghunandan who gave me the link that includes all style attributes. It took me a while but I went through that file and found very interesting elements. Definitely have a look at the link posted below to explore theme styles.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: works for me after call `new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialog)`

Answer (score 15):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/NDFo9pF8sHY

From Dianne Hackborn suggestion

Use non-dialog theme as `android.R.style.Theme` or `android.R.style.Theme_Light`.

Look @ the themes

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml.

Check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

```
DialogFragment picker = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
picker.setStyle( DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme );
picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");
```

Comment: Finally! My problem was the parent theme : `parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`
Changed to another theme keeps my dialogfragment with a good aspect and margins.

Comment: Your solution is works for me. But my dialog box getting a yellow border when invoking DialogFragment from onTextQuerySubmit(). Do you know about that?

Comment: @Kousalya this answers was answeres in 2013. its better you ask a new question regerding this.

Answer (score 10):

if you set this theme to your dialog it will always be fullscreen

```
<!-- DIALOG STYLE -->
<style name="You.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

to do so you can use this [setStyle(int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setStyle%28int,%20int%29) method.

```
dialogFragment.setStyle( DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.You_Dialog );
```

Comment: I am trying your solution. I don't want it full screen, I just want to remove the padding from side if I use any one of these themes I loose all control over programmatically assigning it any parameters.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to know that handling of full screen in Dialog fragment is different from the normal Dialog component, second you need to customize the Dialog fragment before the actual creation of the dialog @ (OnCreateDialog), according to the answer of "user3244180" [Full screen DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887340/full-screen-dialogfragment)

```
 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     // the content
     final RelativeLayout root = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
     root.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

     // creating the fullscreen dialog
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     dialog.setContentView(root);
     dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
     dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     return dialog;
 }
```

Comment: A `FrameLayout` would work just as well, and it's a lighter ViewGroup. Also -- I noticed no difference when I omitted `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me with support for < API 11.

Create a style that is both full screen and has a transparent background:

```
<style name="TransparentDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then your DialogFragment code:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

     public static MyDialog newInstance() {
         MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
         dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.TransparentDialog);
         return dialog;
     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Finally, just for clarity, the contents of my_custom_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.kabx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/semi_transparent_grey" >

..........................
..Whatever You Want Here..
..........................

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

I met the issue before: there is always a padding while having set fullscreen. try this code in dialogFragment's onActivityCreated() method:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    LayoutParams attributes = window.getAttributes();
    //must setBackgroundDrawable(TRANSPARENT) in onActivityCreated()
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    if (needFullScreen)
    {
        window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="WideDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>

@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.WideDialog);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

DialogFragment (when not told explicitly), will use its inner styles that will wrap your custom layout in it (no fullscreen, etc.).

No need to create custom theme for this problem. Just use this method and set style and theme of your choosing:

```
/* theme is optional, I am using leanback... */
setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme_Leanback);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works perfectly for me. It lets me have a full-width dialog (fills the screen's width with no padding) but with wrap_content for height, and it retains all my other stylings that I do in my builder:

```
<style name="DialogTheme">

    <item name="windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>

</style>
```

Background is required or else it does a weird repeat thing, but just set this to the color you want your dialog background to be. WindowBackground and WindowIsFloating are required to make the size wrap correctly.

Add your theme to your builder like so:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting huge side padding in the DialogFragment for Nexus 6p and Pixel.

Fixed that by defining custom style as follows:

```
<style name="Custom.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth" >
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

**parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth** did the trick

Answer (score 0):

For fullscreen dialog I have posted a answer

[In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758070/4314323)

Please check this is the most efficient and shortest way.
Hope this helps :)