# DialogFragment gravity not showing dialog completely in corner

Tags: android, android-layout

I want dialog to appear completely in corner. I am setting gravity this way:

```
    Window win = dialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = win.getAttributes();
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
    wmlp.horizontalMargin = 0;
    wmlp.verticalMargin = 0;
```

Margins don't affect anything here. Layout inspector also doesn't work on dialog so I can't really inspect what is setting margin/padding.

[image]

Can I show this dialog fragment completely in corner (without recreating custom overlay fragment over whole screen that acts as a dialog)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That extra padding/margin may have something to do with the background drawable. Change the style of your dialog to set `android:windowBackground` and `android:background` to be transparent by doing something like this:

```
    <style name="TransparentDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

(I believe that `android:windowBackground` is important here, and you may not need to set `android:background`.)

Thanks goes to andrew who answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536439/dialogfragment-fullscreen-shows-padding-on-sides) for helping to provide a solution.