# Fragment Dialog landscape, fill screen

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem with a fragment dialog, if the phone is on portrait mode, everything is ok, the dialog is almost full screen, but when I rotate my phone, in landscape there are some big gaps on the sides..is possible to fix this problem?

[image]

I call this

```
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

To get rid of the DIalogFragment title.
I'm using a Linear Layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Screen DialogFragment in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189948/full-screen-dialogfragment-in-android)

Comment: @LittleChild Do CTRL + F on that question. Tell me if you find the word 'landscape'. Thanks.

Comment: If you only read rather than a CTRL+F  `android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}
```

Add this to your dialog fragment.