# Under what circumstances does orientation specification not work

Tags: android, screen-orientation

My app sets the screen orientation explicitly in the activity declaration in Manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

However, the orientation is always landscape.  Furthermore, there is no option for enabling orientation in `settings>display` or `settings>accessibility`.

Under what circumstances will Android determine the orientation?

Using API 19.  I am running my app on this [Android PC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AZR1TG2).

Comment: seems interesting......!
android:screenOrientation="portrait" should work under all cases.

Comment: Where are you testing your app?

Answer (score 1):

This, most likely, is not possible for your "Android Mini PC RK3288".  Based on your observations that there is no settings control for auto-rotate enable/disable or orientation config and that this device uses an HDMI connection for a screen output, it is likely to be hardcoded to always output in landscape. Hoewever, you should reach out to manufacturer for and ask them to verify this.  Maybe they have details or secrets to enable this? It cant hurt to ask.

In the meantime,  it is possible to perform  [Rotating a view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android).  This workaround, ought to work for you.

HTHs

Comment: Rotating my be an intriguing workaround.  I will keep you posted.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it orients the way I desire, but since the screen is (1920x1032), there is space on the top and bottom - a lot of space.

Comment: try `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` or make  you ui show in a [dialog fragment that is full screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189948/full-screen-dialogfragment-in-android/26163346)

Comment: Sorry, that did not have any affect.

Comment: While it's not officially the answer to the question.  Your suggestion has resolved my dilemma in the short-term.  BTW, the space on the top and bottom were overcome with negative margin values.  Thank you!!!

Comment: nice.  glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

At the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) there is a **Note**

> Note: When you declare one of the landscape or portrait values, it is
>   considered a hard requirement for the orientation in which the
>   activity runs. As such, the value you declare enables filtering by
>   services such as Google Play so your application is available only to
>   devices that support the orientation required by your activities. For
>   example, if you declare either "landscape", "reverseLandscape", or
>   "sensorLandscape", then your application will be available only to
>   devices that support landscape orientation. However, you should also
>   explicitly declare that your application requires either portrait or
>   landscape orientation with the  element. For example,
>   . This
>   is purely a filtering behavior provided by Google Play (and other
>   services that support it) and the platform itself does not control
>   whether your app can be installed when a device supports only certain
>   orientations.

So I guess that the device you are using has something different in this support or does not support it at all!

Something else that you should have in mind is that you can install/test such apps throw adb to devices that the Google Play will not allow to be installed due to these filtering features.

---

Another way to force orientation is by using

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

before setting the screen of each activity
 ie. before the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` .

Even this code is not sure that is going to work on your device.

In the past, I have got reports of strange behaviors regarding orientation locking but it was quite the opposite as the `setRequestedOrientation` doesn't work whereas the lock thought `AndroidManifest.xml` is working.