# How to set DialogFragment in full screen?

Tags: android

I have seen similar questions, but i couldn't solve it with their answers..

Also i'm using one library to show DialogFragment with blur background effect.
This is my code and how could i make this Dialog set on full screen.

```
public class AddBirthday extends DialogFragment {

private BlurDialogFragmentHelper mHelper;

public static AddBirthday newInstance() {
    AddBirthday fragment = new AddBirthday();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHelper = new BlurDialogFragmentHelper(this);
    mHelper.onCreate();
}

// implement either onCreateView or onCreateDialog
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_birthday, container, false);

    return v;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mHelper.onActivityCreated();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mHelper.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    mHelper.onDismiss();
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full Screen DialogFragment in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189948/full-screen-dialogfragment-in-android)

Comment: Yes i know about that, but i couldn't find a solution in my case, so that's why i have posted a new question on that topic.

Comment: If you want show exactly as dialog your DialogFragment then you need to set style like specified by link above. But if you need to show your dialog in the separate screen you also can use it like fragment to inflate it into fullscreen activity.

Comment: If it can to believe topic by link then you need to put: setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light); at the end of onCreate()