# Full Screen loading dialog won't go completely full screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to use an image as the background for my loading dialog. The dialog is supposed to be full screen, but all I get is this...

[image: Dialog Example]

How can I make the dialog fill the screen so I don't have that white border?

Heres my layout xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/locating"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/kumalocating">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="LOCATING OFFERS IN YOUR AREA"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loader_1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my class...

```
public class SpinnerDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static String message;

    public SpinnerDialog() {
        // use empty constructors. If something is needed use onCreate's
        message = null;
    }

    public static SpinnerDialog spinnerWithCustomMessage(String msg) {
        SpinnerDialog d = new SpinnerDialog();
        message = msg;

        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fill_dialog, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Code to show:

```
    spinnerDialog = SpinnerDialog.spinnerWithCustomMessage(getString(R.string.lo‌​ading_message)); 
spinnerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

Comment: Thats the behaviour of Dialog fragment, however you can override it by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623185/2700586

Comment: @Mani I cant get it t work with a view. Im editing my question to show the java code

Comment: Post the code of how you show spinnerdialog

Comment: @Mani  spinnerDialog = SpinnerDialog.spinnerWithCustomMessage(getString(R.string.loading_message));
                spinnerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
}
```

Add above code inside the SpinnerDialog class!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the Java class.

```
 Dialog mydialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

**Edit**

Add the following line in the SpinnerDialog.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
 }
```

Comment: cant get this to work in my class. I added the java code to the question