# How to make a popup take all screen size

Tags: android, android-studio, popup

I'm creating an mobile app on Android Studio, and I have a list of shows where, if I click on one of them, it displays a popup with all informations on the clicked show.

I'm creating my popup like this :

```
class ShowPopup(private val adapter : ShowAdapter, private val currentShow : ShowModel) : Dialog(adapter.context) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.popup_show_details)
        setupComponents() // Define the values of each fields of the popup
}
```

And here I show the popup on click:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Get show info
        val currentShow = showList[position]

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            ShowPopup(this, currentShow).show()
        }
    }
```

My issue here is that, when clicking on the show, my popup only takes a small amount of space. I tried setting the `width` and `height` of my popup layout but it doesn't take full screen, even if I go past my screen size, I just don't get all content displayed...I'd be grateful if someone could explain how I could achieve putting my popup fullscreen. Thank you in advance !

Here is my layout code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Popup content -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this piece of code to your dialog class

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    window?.apply {
        setLayout(
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
    }
}
```

To be honest, fullscreen dialogs are always pain in.. you know. But this fix does always work for me. You can also take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189948/full-screen-dialogfragment-in-android), it has plenty ways and a lot of discussed stuff.